# How to deploy mern stack app on production?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, cloud

I’m willing to deploy my mern stack app, I have been surfing through internet I didn’t find a production platform to host my app, I juste found host for test.
Please help

I tried to search but didn’t find anything suitable , I went on Heroku I couldn’t host react there

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to build the app through **npm run build** command.
After that you can upload the build folder to [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/)

I suppose your app is a SPA app. So before running the build command you need to create a file name `_redirects` under your project root directory. Then include this line on that file:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```

This will handle the react route redirects so that the page won't reload. Rather it will work as a SPA. If your app is not a SPA then don't need to create it.